# fontawesome the style dont work laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I work on Laravel 7 project , when i use fontawesome the icon don't work

i have the file in public directory then i used in app.blade.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/css/vendor/vendor.min.css')}}">
```

she don't work
then i install the fontawesome with `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` command and `npm install && npm run dev` then `npm run production` but still don't work .

sass file

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

any solution

Comment: Pretty sure your asset link is wrong and hence broken. Can you give a description of the directory structure/path where your output css is stored relative to your application root?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did `npm run prod` you should get an `app.css` or a file with `CSS` extension.

You can check in your `webpack` file, to findout, what is the output for `CSS` file.

In case you've done `npm run prod` base on default `Laravel` setup, you should get the `app.css` file in `CSS` directory, which in this case you can now use that file using below code :

```
<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Highly recommend to use `mix()` in this case, since you're using `npm run production` and getting output base on messing with `CSS` and `JS` files in resource directory.